# Bash cat on the last created remote file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I am trying to recover the content of the last created file on a remote server.

When connected to the remote server I do this:

```
cat `ls -t /mypath/*.csv | head -1`
CMD="cat `ls -t /mypath/*.txt | head -1`"
```

But when I try to use the same command:

```
ssh@XX.XX.XX.XX $CMD
```

I get an error: ls cannot access /mypath/*.csv No such file or directory.
The ` is forcing to execute the ls on the local system on not the remote.

Is there another way?

Thank you

Comment: The problem is due to the command with the pipe being stored in a variable.  See the linked question.

Comment: Use single quotes, not double

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command is failing is because the backticks in $CMD are expanded locally when you create the variable, rather than being expanded on the remote side. So `ssh@XX.XX.XX.XX $CMD` is actually going to look something like `ssh@XX.XX.XX.XX "cat /mypath/local_file"` (and `local_file` may not exists on the remote host, and is probably not the file you want).

You can prevent this local expansion by providing the command directly to ssh.

```
ssh user@host 'cat /mypath/$(ls -t /mypath/*.txt | head -1)'
```

`ls` returns the pathname relative to the directory so you will also need to include the path of the base directory `/mypath/` in your cat invocation. To avoid this hardcoding pass the `-d` flag to `ls`.

```
ssh user@host 'cat $(ls -dt /mypath/*.txt | head -1)'
```

Comment: The `cat here wasn't useless, he wants the contents of the file, by removing it you're just printing the name.

Comment: @Kevin, right, I'm an idiot. Fixed and thanks.

Comment: The ssh... 'cat $(ls -dt /mypath/*.txt | head -1)' works! Thank you!

Comment: @Alain, no problem. If you found this answer helpful, then I would suggest "accepting" it, so it can be helpful to others with the same issue in the future.